# ssh into a machine and search for process, kill using xargs

Tags: ssh, kill, xargs

I am doing this,

```
guastest@iridium06.psc ~> ssh <machine> jps | gawk '$2 == "<process>" {print $1}' | xargs kill
kill: sending signal to 75797 failed: No such process
guastest@iridium06.psc ~> echo $?
123
```

But is working if I put it this way

```
ssh <machine> "jps | gawk '\$2 == \"<process>\" {print \$1}' | xargs kill "
```

Why is that so ?

Comment: eliminate what, exactly?  You should edit your question so what your looking to eliminate is clear.

Comment: the exit status is 123 and the process is not getting killed

Comment: First thing to do is check the output: remove the `>&` clause, or redirect to a file. Edit your question to include the results of this.

Comment: You will need to *edit* your question and clarify your question.  Clarification submitted by comment is subject to be removed for being too chatty.

Comment: See djsmiley2k's answer..

Answer (score 2):

Your second version of the command sends the entire command (in " .... " ) to the server to be executed there, your first version sends only the first part `jps` to the server, and then executes the rest of the command using the output on the local machine.